# Function calls within lapply

Tags: r, lapply

I am a relative newbie with R and have been repeatedly carrying out functions on multiple matrices.  Just recently I have begun to use lapply to simplify my coding.

So I now have a list containing six matrices, with each matrix having the same dimensions.  I have been successfully building my own functions and applying them to the matrix thus:

```
matrixlist.new <- lapply(matrixlist.old,Mycustomfunction)
```

But despite reading around the subject I am struggling to get a simple pre-existing R function to work within lapply.

My specific question now is that I would like to extract the maximum value from the third column in each of my matrices into a new list, that would have one value for each of the matrices in my original list.

Were I to have a single matrix the code would be:

```
maxofcol3 <- max(matrix[,3])
```

But how do I combine this simple function into lapply without making this simple code into a custom function (which I could do, but which seems like it can't be the simplest approach)?

I have tried all sorts of combinations but can't get my head around this...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you consider passing an unnamed function to be too complex here?

Comment: I agree with @Dason that an anonymous function would be totally fine here.

Comment: `maxofcol3 <- lapply(matrixlist.old, function(m) max(m[, 3))`. This returns a list in `maxofcol3`. If you want a vector as a return value, use `sapply`.

Comment: I knew that this would end up being ridiculously simple.  Dason - no I do not consider passing an unnamed function to be too complex, I had just not picked up that one could do that.  Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Because we like reproducible examples...

```
matrixlist.old <- rep(list(matrix(data=rnorm(9),3)),times=3)

lapply(matrixlist.old,function(x) max(x[,3]))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 0.828354
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 0.828354
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 0.828354

sapply(matrixlist.old,function(x) max(x[,3]))
#> [1] 0.828354 0.828354 0.828354
```

Created on 2019-02-28 by the reprex package (v0.2.1)

Comment: Thanks Art and Dason, that was useful for me to start understanding the difference between sapply and lapply.